# How to show formGroups based on mat-button-toggle selection in angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, formgroups

I am using angular 8 and using  from angular material [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview)

I want to be able to display different formGroups(1 or 2 input fields) based on each mat button toggle selection. But i am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Try something first and ask a question if you get stuck. Remember to include a [mcve]

Comment: The aproach can be make a FormGroup with **all** the fields necesary and use `*ngIf` to show the formControls (the inputs) you want. You can use [(ngModel)] for the toogle-buttons and ask about the variable, but really it's hard help you with so few data